# Model form - How to change default ManyToMany widget?

Tags: django

I use Django Model Form:

```
class Fruit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Box(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=199)
    fruit = models.ManyToManyField(Fruit)
```

and forms.py:

```
class BoxModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Box
```

I have default django ManyToMany widget in form:

http://nov.imghost.us/ly5M.png

How can I change this to input (text type) and if I type into this input:

> apple,banana,lemon - comma separated

this `Fruit` will be created?

Answer (score 2):

As stated here in the documentation :https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields
You can add a widgets attribute to the `Meta` of your `Modelform` to change the default widgets used in the form.

In your case it would be something like this :

```
class BoxModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Box
        widgets = {
            'fruit': TheWidgetYouWantToUse(),
        }
```

But actually for the behavior you want to achieve, you could proceed another way.
You should add an extra text field, and write the addition/removal of fruits in the save step, while checking the validity of the differents tags in the clean step.

```
class BoxModelForm(ModelForm):
    fruit_selector = forms.TextField(
          max_length=255,
          tag = 'Whatever'
          )
    class Meta:
        model = Box
        fields = ['user','name']

    def clean_fruit_selector(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['fruit_selector']
        # Check that data are corrects ie the string is correctly formatted
        # If not raise validation error
        ....
        fruit_tags = data.split(",")

        #Check that all tags are fruit or raise a validation error

        ...
        return data #or only the list of correct tags

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(MyForm, self).save(commit=False)

        # Compare the list of tags fruit_tags with self.instance.fruit.all()
        ....
        # Take the right actions

        if commit:
            instance.save()
        return instance
```

Look into this page for more details on how to change the field validation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/

This is just a schematic.

Answer (score 0):

[django-taggit](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit) is a perfect app for this use case.

Define your models like this:

```
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager
from taggit.models import TagBase, GenericTaggedItemBase


class Fruit(TagBase):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Fruit"
        verbose_name_plural = "Fruits"

class TaggedFruit(GenericTaggedItemBase):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Fruit,
                            related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_items")

class Box(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=199)
    fruits = TaggableManager(through=TaggedFruit)
```

Then create basic model form:

```
class BoxModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Box
```

And that's it! You can now add fruit tags into your box, separated by comma. In case the fruit doesn't exist, it will be added into Fruit table. Read the [docs](http://django-taggit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) for more details on how to use *django-taggit*.

You can use it together with jquery based [Selectize.js](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/).